# Is there any impact if we deploy the war files which is built on JDK 1.6.0.35 on production?

Tags: java, java-6

In production environment we are using JDK 1.6.0.26. is any impact if we deploy the war files which is built on JDK 1.6.0.35?

Comment: since it's the same major version, I doubt it, but why do you still run Java 6 on production?

Answer (score 1):

One can not be certain :)

In theory java is backward compatible which means that newer runtime can run code build for older runtime. But the other way is not true.

In your case only the minor minor version differ and I believe it will be ok.

Don't forget to run your end to end tests to verify that everything is working ;)

Comment: The "minor minor" version is usually referred to as the *micro* version.